# Know the number of elements of a Iqueryable

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have this Linq Query

```
public IQueryable listAll()
{   
    ModelQMDataContext db = new ModelQMDataContext(); 
    IQueryable lTax = from t
                      in db.tax
                      select new {Tax = t.tax1, Increase = t.increase};
    return  lTax;
}
```

how can I know the number of elements of lTax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really need to return `IQueryable`? Returning `IQueryable` from your method doesn't provide much functionality since you can't access the members of an anonymous type without reflection. In this case I suggest that you create a concrete type in the query to be able to return `IQueryable<T>`:

```
class TaxIncrease
{
    public int Tax { get; set; }
    public int Increase { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<TaxIncrease> listAll() {
    ModelQMDataContext db = new ModelQMDataContext();
    return from t in db.tax
           select new TaxIncrease {Tax = t.tax1, Increase = t.increase};
}
```

and then you can do:

[`listAll().Count();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx)

Comment: This was my first option, but lTax has not a Count method and I don't know Why...

Comment: It should do (as an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`). What happens if you try to call `Count()` on it?

Comment: Ok. I see what your problem is. You should be using the generic version of IQueryable<T> instead and then you can get the *free* extension methods like Count.

Answer (score 2):

lTax.Count() should do it...

Comment: This was my first option, but lTax has not a Count method and I don't know Why...

Answer (score 0):

first declare lTax as `List`, so can have `.Count()`

Then you can change this to Queryable if you want by `lTax.AsQueryable()`